# SP2010: SharePoint Ribbon Not Visible for Rich Text Field

Tags: 2010, ribbon, list-form, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I've a list form where I've enabled enhanced rich text for a multiline text column. But, I'm unable to see the SP ribbon when I place my cursor on the textbox. I'm not using any JS code on the form. So, not sure what is causing it.

Comment: are you using a custom master page? there might be a script etc. causing it. if you can, try removing the custom master and see if it works then

Comment: Is it happening in all browsers?

Comment: No, I'm not using any custom master page. Yes, it is happening in all browsers. Is there any way to force display the ribbon using JS?

Comment: Are you using a team site or a publishing site?

Comment: I'm using a team site.